# Two way flow in a producer / consumer scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to find a solution for a queuing problem I have. In the typical scenario, the producer puts something on the queue and the consumer takes it off. How about if we have a producer that also consumes and  a consumer that initially takes something off the queue and then puts something (like a result) back on the queue. As such, there is a two way flow if you follow. Is it possible to synchronize two threads to do this effectively? Naively, I had put a loop in the run method of one of my threads only to discover that the other thread will only run once and then dies.. Apologies if this appears vague..Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction

Cheers

Comment: The producer should count the number of responses it expects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, you can put and take from it from any thread. There is no strict distinction between producer and consumer threads and the queue object guarantees consistency of each operation.